# How do I add the noscript tag?

Tags: 8

I've a drupal 8 website, where in every page, I would like to add a noscript tag for every script tag. In drupal 8, in html.html.twig, I saw the scripts variable in missing. So how do I do that in Drupal 8?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I wound up just putting the `<noscript>` tag into my `html.html.twig` template. There is a [NoScript Tag module](https://www.drupal.org/project/noscript_tag), but I didn't feel like adding a module to my site for this purpose.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in a custom module (MYMODULE.module):

```
use Drupal\Core\Render\Markup;

function MYMODULE_page_attachments(array &$page) {
  $fallback = '<link href="fallback.css" rel="stylesheet" />';
  $noscript = array(
    '#tag' => 'noscript',
    '#value' => Markup::create($fallback),
  );
  $page['#attached']['html_head'][] = [$noscript, 'mymodule'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending where exactly you need the tag to be placed, there's also [`hook_page_top`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_page_top) and [`hook_page_bottom`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_page_bottom) to add markup either after the opening `<body>` tag or right before the `<footer>` tag (or wherever your theme has `{{ page_top }}` and `{{ page_bottom }}` placed exactly inside `html.html.twig`).

Here's a sample that adds some marketing tool's `<script>` and `<noscript>` tags right after the opening `<body>` tag.

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_page_top().
 */
function MYMODULE_page_top(array &$page_top) {

  if (\Drupal::currentUser()->isAnonymous()) {

    $foobar_script = [
      '#type' => 'html_tag',
      '#tag' => 'script',
      '#attributes' => ['src' => 'https://example.com/js/example.js'],
    ];
    $page_top['foobar_script'] = $foobar_script;

    $foobar_noscript = [
      '#type' => 'html_tag',
      '#tag' => 'noscript',
      '#value' => Markup::create('<img alt="" src="https://example.com/foobar.png" style="display:none;" />'),
    ];
    $page_top['foobar_noscript'] = $foobar_noscript;
  }
}
```